# How can I change the Type GUI Element from TextView to HTMLView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a code, that is a website and I need to write an App, that shows just this page.
But the problem is that my code didn't see the Hyperlinks because I need to change from TextView to HTMLView.
this is the code:

```
    public class BlackBoardClient {
    private static final String BLACK_BOARD_URL = "https://zpa.cs.hm.edu/public/notice_board/";
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

    public static List<BlackBoardEntry> getBlackBoardEntries() throws IOException  {
        List<BlackBoardEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(BLACK_BOARD_URL).get();
        Element newsTable = doc.getElementById("content").selectFirst("table");
        Iterable<Element> rows = newsTable.selectFirst("tbody").children();

        for (Element row : rows) {
            Iterator<Element> columns = row.children().iterator();
            String author = columns.next().text();
            String title = columns.next().text();
            String content = columns.next().text();
            LocalDate validFrom = LocalDate.parse(columns.next().text(), FORMATTER);
            LocalDate validUntil = LocalDate.parse(columns.next().text(), FORMATTER);
            BlackBoardEntry entry = new BlackBoardEntry(author, title, content, validFrom, validUntil);
            entries.add(entry);
        }

        return entries;
    }
}
```

It shows like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGask.png)

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView dataList = findViewById(R.id.dataList);

        dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                BlackBoardEntry entry = (BlackBoardEntry) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String content = entry.getContent();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_popup, null, false);
                ((TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.contentView)).setText(content);

                PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, 500, 1000, true);
                popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


                }
        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    List<BlackBoardEntry> entries = BlackBoardClient.getBlackBoardEntries();
                    BlackBoardAdapter adapter = new BlackBoardAdapter(entries, getApplicationContext());
                    dataList.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For just showing Web-Content from an existing URL, I would recommend to implement an Android WebView.

Your current popup-View is defined as Android TextView:

```
((TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.contentView)).setText(content);
```

Change this to a WebView (in the xml "Design-/Layout-View" Tool)

For an example look at Android Developer Docs https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

It is straigt forward to use, you can invoke JS if necessary.

Dont forget to change your manifest-file for permissions.

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```